# How to make my FOR XML SQL query faster?

Tags: sql, xml, performance, sqlxml

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ( -- Subquery to get associated rows in View2 as XML.
        SELECT
            *
        FROM View2
        WHERE
            View1_Print.SchedId = View2.SchedId AND
            PublishDay BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate FOR XML PATH('Answer') 
    ) AS Answers
FROM View1_Print
FOR XML PATH('View1'), ROOT('ArrayOfView1');
```

The above SQL appears to correctly retrieve all rows in View1 along with an XML representation of the associated rows in View2, which is what I want.  The problem is that this query takes four minutes to execute.  Each view has several thousand rows.

When I run an ordinary query with a join statement, it executes in just six seconds, but I'm looking for an efficient way to serialize this result to XML.  Here's my query without the XML that runs in six seconds:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
View1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN View2 B
    ON A.SchedId = B.SchedId AND B.PublishDay BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate;
```

It should be retrieving the exact same format, so why is my XML query so slow?

Comment: The execution plans are probably different . . . For instance, the `for xml` query might be using a nested loop join.  Can you post the execution plans for the two queries?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a query with outer apply instead of sub query as shown below.  Please note this is not complete answer you need to modify it according to your requirement and solve errors if any.

```
SELECT *,Answers.A,Answers.B 
FROM View1_Print
OUTER APPLY  ( -- Subquery to get associated rows in View2 as XML.
        SELECT
            View2.Col1 as A,View2.Col2 as B
        FROM View2
        WHERE
            View1_Print.SchedId = View2.SchedId AND
            PublishDay BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate FOR XML PATH('Answer') 
    ) AS Answers
FOR XML PATH('View1'), ROOT('ArrayOfView1');
```

Comment: +1: I have solved this problem by rewriting my code to not use `FOR XML`.  Thanks for the answer.  I'll try it next time I want to convert SQL rows to XML.